# Does an FCM message's "icon" property have any effect on iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM messages can contain an `"icon"` key in the `"notification"` object, which is displayed as the notification's icon on Android. Does the `"icon"` property get used in any way when included in a message sent to an iOS device, or is it disregarded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `icon` parameter does not affect iOS.

You can find a list of parameters and their effect on each platform here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support